# Can I change the env value of Hasura Cloud from the CLI?

Tags: hasura, hasura-cli

Hasura Cloud is in use. I want to synchronize environmental variables in GitHub action at all times for this project. Is there an option to read the .env file from the CLI and apply it to Hasura Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Hasura Cloud API in your Github Action https://hasura.io/docs/latest/api-reference/cloud-api-reference/#update-env-vars